How to drain a water heater tank that doesn’t have a regular spigot
My mom just purchased a home with a GE profile water heater (gas). I went to drain it today and discovered the tank outlet at the bottom isn’t what I expected. There’s no valve that I can see. Is there a plumber on this board that can guide me to draining said tank? Photos for clarity.



That's a perfectly normal water heater drain. Attach a hose to the male threads sticking out and rotate the white part and hose attached counterclockwise.
Since you didn't give a model number I checked a random GE Profile Gas Water Heater manual, and it had this style of drain, but they evidently consider the operation sufficiently obvious that they give no instructions for it.
